# UWP TextBox Text Orientation Problems

Tags: c#, xaml, file-io, textbox, win-universal-app

I am writing a Windows 10 UWP app in which I open plain text files and display the contents of said file in a textbox. But I have some weird problems displaying some of the files. Upon opening some files, the orientation of the textbox shifts from the usual 'left to right' to 'right to left', even though in the XAML code it's specified to be 'left to right'.

This only happens when I open the file using this piece of code (Only if I set the enconding to UTF8, if I set it to ANSI, the textbox will display the text with the appropriate orientation, but the files I am trying to open are not in ANSI):

```
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
            DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
            byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
            reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
            string fileText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
```

If I use this other code, it will display correctly, but it crashes upon opening some other text files:

```
string fileText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: With the first piece of code (UTF8)]

[image: With the second piece of code (Or with ANSI)]

I'm seriously deeply confused by this, will really appreciate any help.

Edit: Here's the XAML code for the textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MainTextBox"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             Grid.Row="2"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
             TextChanged="MainTextBox_TextChanged"
             PointerEntered="MainTextBox_PointerEntered"
             PointerExited="MainTextBox_PointerExited"/>
```

Comment: Please post the xaml code

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem by using your above code. Did you mean some of the files can display correctly, but some of them cannot? If this, mostly is the the problem of the file. Upload the >"some of the files".

Comment: I've added the XAML code for the textbox to my question.

Comment: I've also just noticed that this only happens to UTF-8 text files with a BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way around it, and realized that I wasn't using the correct property in my textbox XAML code.

Instead of using

```
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
```

I used:

```
TextAlignment="Left"
```

And it now stopped aligning the text to the right whenever it pleased.

Edit:

Actually the above didn't solve all of the problems, so I had to remove the BOM (the first three bytes of the UTF-8 file) from the file that I wanted to load, because for some reason that is what causes the text to appear reverted in the textbox.

It's just so ironic that Microsoft being one of the only devs/companies that make their programs (e.g. Notepad, Visual Studio) add a BOM in the UTF-8 files they save, include a buggy textbox in their "star" platform (UWP) that doesn't work fine with a UTF-8 BOM.